# Saving n individual objects to a class

Tags: python, list, class, if-statement

I'm making a phonebook and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have defined a class "people" which should create individual "profiles" for each person that enters in their name and phone-number. Then I have a function that works as the UI for the user. The problem occurs when you try to "lookup" a profile using the name. Python simply tells me that the string object given(the name) doesn't have a "number" attribute.

The code:

```
class people:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

def main():
    while True:
        command = str(input(('phoneBook> ')))
        segment = command.split()

        if segment[0] == 'add':

            segment[1] = people(segment[2])
            print(segment[1].number)

        if segment[0] == 'lookup':

            print(segment[1].number)

        if segment[0] == 'quit':
            pass
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and any tips on working with classes or on this specific issue would be great!

Thanks! - TheBigChung

Comment: because you don't define `segment[1]` as `people` in the second `if statement`

Comment: Shouldn't it already exist as an object of `people` bcs I defined it earlier? wouldn't that create a second object? @Matiiss

Comment: @TheBigChung Sure, but then the loop starts over from the top and evaluates `segment = command.split()`

Comment: As it should, so if I for example type: > add Jones 106524. It should first add the number: 106524 with Jones being the object variable. And on the second loop I type: > lookup Jones, it should output the attribute (number): 106524. @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the 'lookup' part, you are not accessing a people object's number attribute, just accessing the number attribute on a string.
one way to do what you want is to keep a dictionary of all people's objects using something as a key(for example their name).

then when you have a 'lookup' query, map the segment[1] the relevant object and return it.
also, you can change the attributes of these objects and access them later.

Comment: I think I might have figured it out using the method you suggested(dictionary). I created a dictionary inside of `people` and a function inside of `people` that added `number` with the key `segment[1]`. Then to add the name and number to the dictionary i called people.dictionaryName[segment[1]] = segment[2] and to get the output of the dict i simply called: print(people.DictionaryName[segment1])

Comment: One more question tho, if you don't mind? can i assign an alias to a dictionary key?

Comment: @TheBigChung what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Matiiss nvm, I figured out a way to do that. What i meant was: If you can create alias a key in a dictionary, so that you can access the value of the key through the first given key and the alias variable of the first given key.